# Conditional visibility and calculated expressions for new and edit forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, edit-form, newform, visual-studio-2015

We need help regarding visibility and dynamic calculated expressions inside new and edit forms (not the standard calculated fields from SharePoint). Until now we used mostly Ardevia Rich Forms for building custom forms.

We are now working on a Visual Studio project and we are building a list with custom new,edit and display forms. We know how to sort the fields and make changes in the layout. Now we are going into the next phase: visibility and calculated expressions inside new and edit form. Our main problem is to make the same without third party tools.

Are there somewhere good examples how to make these kind of expressions?

Best reagrds

Comment: It depends on the rest of your code. If your logic is client-side create JS functions on the fly and parse them with eval, saves you from building a parser from scratch. I'm sure you could do similar server-side (I don't touch .Net.. its the Cobol of 2017)

Comment: Are there somewhere good examples how do that? I am not very familiar with scripts. Is it possible to insert codes directly into new and edit forms?

Comment: Learn CSR (Client Side Rendering)